# No such file or directory in Android

Tags: android, file-io

I'm facing a problem when copying a file in the external sdcard:
here is what i get in the log message:

```
04-06 17:52:36.804: DEBUG/Carburant(258): Sdcard can read/write !!
04-06 17:52:36.864: DEBUG/Carburant(258): /mnt/sdcard/mnt/sdcard/settings.dat (No such file or directory)
```

And here is my code:

```
public class Import {
    private Context context;
    private String nom;


    public Import(Context context,String nom) {
        this.context = context;
        this.nom=nom;
       }

    public void transfer(){

    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    boolean mExternalStorageAvailable = false;
    boolean mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        // We can read and write the media
        Log.d("Carburant", "Sdcard can read/write !!" ); 
        mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true;
        File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File nmea_file = new File(root,"settings.dat");
        copyfile(nom,sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + nmea_file);
    } else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        // We can only read the media
        Log.d("Carburant", "Sdcard only read !!" ); 
        mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
        mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
    } else {
        // Something else is wrong. It may be one of many other states, but all we need
        //  to know is we can neither read nor write
        mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
    }
```

And here is my copyfile func:

```
private void copyfile(String srFile, String dtFile){
        try{
            File f1 = new File(srFile);
            File f2 = new File(dtFile);
          InputStream in = new FileInputStream(f1);
          OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f2);

          byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
          int len;
          while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0){
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
          }
          in.close();
          out.close();
          Toast.makeText(context, "Export effectu�", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
            Toast.makeText(context, "File Not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String x=ex.getMessage();
            Log.d("Carburant", x);
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Echec", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();      
        }
      }
```

i don't know why the compiler gives /mnt/sdcard/mnt/sdcard/settings.dat as output file, there is duplicate in the /mnt/sdcard...
Thank you for your help.

```
File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/Carburant/");
        dir.mkdirs();
        File file = new File(dir, "settings.dat");
        copyfile(nom,dir.getAbsolutePath());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
copyfile(nom, nmea_file.getAbsolutePath());
```

instead.

You are getting one `"/mnt/sdcard"` from the `root` variable and another one from the `sdCard` variable.

Comment: @Matthew Willis:The problem is nmea_file is of type file and the copy function takes 2 string parameters! i change the second parameter of copyfile func ?

Comment: I updated the code to use `getAbsolutePath`, which will give you a `String`.

Comment: @Matthew Willis: excellent answer! But i don't know why the file is stored in the /sdcard/LOST.DIR/settings.dat ?

Comment: @Matthew Willis: no errors! But please, how can i export the file not in the root of sdcard but in a directory? please edit your answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: Take a look at the File class. There is a `mkdir` method that you can use to create a directory.

Comment: @Matthew Willis: so is that true ? i have file not found exception! have i to add FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file); in a try block ? Thank you.

Comment: Where is your FileNotFoundException?

Comment: @Matthew Willis: please see the copyfile function.

Comment: @Matthew Willis: i have this log message: 04-06 19:27:42.694: DEBUG/Carburant(6079): /mnt/sdcard/Carburant (Is a directory)

Comment: In the last line, replace `dir` with `file`.

Answer (score 2):

because you do this
your nmea_file has already based on the root..
copyfile(nom,**sdCard.getAbsolutePath()+ nmea_file**)

Comment: so i just remove sdCard.getAbsolutePath() ??

Comment: yes, i think so.. another funny thing you have made is that your copyfile function has two String parameter, but you pass something String + File i.e. sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + nmea_file